# LINQ: Is it possible to write Select (using query syntax) with some additional code before returning a result of projection?

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to write this (just as example):

```
var objects = new List<object>{ new object(), null };

var strings = objects.Select(o =>
{
   if (o == null) 
   {
      throw new Exception();
   }

   return o.ToString();
});
```

using LINQ query syntax (without extracting method)?

Comment: _Is it possible_ Yes, no, maybe. What have you tried so far to learn this?

Comment: LINQ should not cause side effects. Throwing an exception is a side effect. But of course it's possible. Write a method that encapsulates your code and call it in the query.

Comment: Just because it can be written in LINQ doesn't mean it should be written in LINQ.

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: and dont get addicted to one line linq ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answers :) The purpose of question was not to find out how to write bad code using query syntax, but to know why is it possible to write this using 'method chain' syntax without extracting a method and is not possible to write using query syntax. Sorry if it was not clear.